# How do you store and replay JDBC statements?

Tags: java, jdbc, xmpp, distributed-computing, smack

Given a JDBC-based application, that was not designed for real-time propagation of changes from one instance of the app running on computer A to another instance runnning on computer B in a two-way synchronization schema. How can you do this elegantly, without using Symmetric DS?

We though of using XMPP and XStream, transforming POJOs to XML or JSON, sending them via the XMPP, Smack API to the pre-configured "chat room" where other bots, listening, would replay the data they receive. Thus, even offline client apps, would receive the "DiscussionHistory" by sending their last "since timestamp".

I kind of looked everywhere for a "near real-time database change propagation" in Java, or even in H2, but where changes are propagated between each node registered, but the only solution I could think of is to use the XMPP protocol, build a "bot" chat-room around it, have nodes send their data there while others listen for changes.

The so-called "bots" are application instances on different computers, of an accounting application that should allow for real-time collaboration on the same database, but allow for offline modifications (so no centralized server to store changes).

Comment: I can't say whether XMPP is the right fit for this or not, but if you are going to use it, then I think pubsub would be a better fit then a chatroom.

Comment: Something like "DiscussionHistory" which is in the Smack API for a MUC (multi-user chat) must be available. Cause nodes may be offline for more than a day. Even a week sometimes. And it's best if they can get 'up-to-speed' by replaying the history since they last logged in. So, still looking at XMPP as an implementation of a MUC between these infrequent nodes to connect to each other and share changes in near real-time. Did not see such support in PubSub. 10x.

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is to build your caching so that the application always queries the database if a particular entry is not found. Then you would only have to synchronize cache-evictions to force all nodes in a group to re-load a certain entry. This is fairly easily achieved using, for instance, spring method caching and ehcache.

Comment: English would be appropriate ... The ideea is what I want to store "inserts, updates and deletes for all queries that go through the app". For each query, I want it to be communicated via XMPP for example to other "bot" instances listening, to be replayed.

Comment: Seems that DebuggableStatement is a PreparedStatement from where I can store the "prepared SQL" after it's prepared. This means that it should be easy to catch "SQL Statements" store them somewhere and when online, let the application send these statements to the "multi-user chat room" for these bots where they get replicated to other nodes that will receive the updates. Wondering if this is a good approach or not. And yes, all our queries go through "one-single-query-method" which makes this scenario feasible.

Comment: So I understand correctly, you're not after synching the actual data but rather each instance has it's own database and you want to propagate each database operation between all instances so the the DATABASE is identical, not just the live, in-memory data. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Corect. They pretty much start from a "seed" database on one of the nodes. Having same structure (100% identically) means that statements could/can be propagated between them, thus making any available copy have the "real-time" data of the last node that successfully communicated its changes via the protocol. The combination of the XMPP protocol with XStream in a "chat-room" for our application instances is the closest thing to replication we could find without knowing ahead how many nodes there will be. But for sure, we want all nodes to communicate with each other.